# How to create a dynamic checkbox list based on dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, json, drop-down-menu, yii2

I want to generate a dynamic checkbox list based on the drop down in yii2. The fields are as follows.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'country')->dropDownList(Countries::getCountries(),
                    ['id' => 'country_id', 'prompt' => 'Select  countries'])
                ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'state')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
                        //'data' => Regions::getRegions($model->country),
                        'options' => ['id' => 'region_id', 'prompt' => 'Choose a country first'],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'depends' => ['country_id'],
                            'placeholder' => 'Select a state',
                            'url' => Url::to(['/regions/regions'])
                        ]
                    ]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'city')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
                        //'data' => Cities::getCities($model->country),
                        'options' => ['id' => 'city_id', 'prompt' => 'Select a state'],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'depends' => ['country_id','region_id'],
                            'placeholder' => 'Select',
                            'url' => Url::to(['/cities/cities'])
                        ]
                    ]) ?>
 <?= $form->field($model, 'publisher_name')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
                    //'data' => Cities::getCities($model->country),
                    'options' => ['id' => 'user_id', 'prompt' => 'Choose a publisher'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'depends' => ['country_id','region_id','city_id'],
                        'placeholder' => 'Select',
                        'url' => Url::to(['/publisher/publishers'])
                    ]
                ]) ?>
```

When I drop all the drop downs it is correctly returning a JSON which is as follows but now instead of drop down I want to create checkboxes how can I do that the JSON which is being returned is as follows

```
{"output":[{"user_id":"109","name":"user1"},{"user_id":"114","name":"user2"}],"selected":""}
```

Controller

```
public function actionPublishers() {
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
if (isset(Yii::$app->request->post()['depdrop_parents'])) {
    $parents = Yii::$app->request->post('depdrop_parents');
    if ($parents != null) {
        $countryID = $parents[0];
        $stateID = $parents[1];
        $cityId = $parents[2];

        return [
            'output' => publisher::getPublishers($countryID,$stateID,$cityId, true),
            'selected' => '',
        ];
    }
}
return ['output' => '', 'selected' => ''];
}
```

Comment: if i understand correctly the above response is received from the dep-dropdowns and you want to populate a checkbox list on the base of the `json` given above?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yes

Comment: then you should populate the checkboxes on the action from where you are getting this response, rather than sending the json you should send the result to the view using `renderAjax()` and populate the checkboxes and use the success function to append the html to the body,  i assume that it comes after selecting the `city`?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yes, it is. I have little knowledge about what you are actually talking about can you show me one example on this?

Comment: OK, add the code for the action that is sending the above `json` response `{"output":[{"user_id":"109","name":"user1"},{"user_id":"114","name":"user2"}],"selected":""}`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam i have added the action